# Can you access HLS closed captioned data through MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, closed-captions

I want to access closed captioned data so that I can use the caption data to control items inside my iOS app.

If we are injecting the caption data from our encoders, is there a way to have our MPMoviePlayerController player kick out the caption objects so we can read them and perform actions after parsing them?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From Apple directly: "There is currently no way to accomplish this."

So you can't get captions or subtitles out of either this player or the AVplayer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to accomplish this with the MPMoviePlayerController, but it can be done with the AVPlayer.

see

```
AVPlayer.closedCaptionDisplayEnabled
```